# Parquet File upload in Druid

Tags: parquet, druid

I am new to the Druid.
I have done a local setup of druid in local and I am able to load files of json data in druid.

However when I am trying to upload a parquet file, it is giving Unexpected character exception.

I've installed Parquet and Avro extensions  and I get following error in each case

$ >curl -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -d @examples/wikipedia_hadoop_parquet_job.json http://localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/task

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 </title>
</head>enter code here
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /druid/indexer/v1/task. Reason:
<pre>    javax.servlet.ServletException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (&apos;}&apos; (code 125)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
 at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@57df7615[c=2032,q=1,[0]=EOF,s=STREAM]; line: 1, column: 493]</pre></p>
<hr /><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.19.v20170502</a><hr/>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the JSON config file

```
{
  "type": "index_hadoop",
  "spec": {
    "ioConfig": {
      "type": "hadoop",
      "inputSpec": {
        "type": "static",
        "inputFormat": "org.apache.druid.data.input.parquet.DruidParquetInputFormat",
        "paths": "example/wikipedia_list.parquet"
      },
      "metadataUpdateSpec": {
        "type": "postgresql",
        "connectURI": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/druid",
        "user" : "druid",
        "password" : "asdf",
        "segmentTable": "druid_segments"
      },

    },
    "dataSchema": {
      "dataSource": "wikipedia",
      "parser": {
        "type": "parquet",
        "parseSpec": {
          "format": "timeAndDims",
          "timestampSpec": {
            "column": "timestamp",
            "format": "auto"
          },
          "dimensionsSpec": {
            "dimensions": [
              "page",
              "language",
              "user",
              "unpatrolled"
            ],
            "dimensionExclusions": [],
            "spatialDimensions": []
          }
        }
      },
      "metricsSpec": [{
        "type": "count",
        "name": "count"
      }, {
        "type": "doubleSum",
        "name": "deleted",
        "fieldName": "deleted"
      }, {
        "type": "doubleSum",
        "name": "delta",
        "fieldName": "delta"
      }],
      "granularitySpec": {
        "type": "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity": "DAY",
        "queryGranularity": "NONE",
        "intervals": ["2013-08-30/2013-09-02"]
      }
    },
    "tuningConfig": {
      "type": "hadoop",
      "workingPath": "tmp/working_path",
      "partitionsSpec": {
        "targetPartitionSize": 5000000
      },
      "leaveIntermediate": true
    }
  }
}
```

I am not able to figure out the issue. Let me know, if I am missing something.

Comment: Hi, I was able to resolve the above issue. There was issue with json config file.  But the druid job is getting failed. On checking the logs, below issue is encountered. Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Class, problem: org.apache.druid.data.input.parquet.DruidParquetInputFormat

Comment: Below exception, I am getting.                            java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.druid.data.input.parquet.DruidParquetInputFormat.                            I am using druid-parquet-extensions:0.12.0

Comment: Try using `io.druid.data.input.parquet.DruidParquetInputFormat` instead.